# float right property block another div

Tags: html, css, css-float

Soas you can see I have three divs. In div "about" I have set a background color, and have some heading,
but when i set float:right property for div "boxes" it blocks div "about".

Can anyone tell me why is that happening?

Thanks!

this is my HTML:

```
<div id="about">

<div id="content_holder">

<div class="boxes_8"><img src="images/jack.jpg" width="227" height="227" alt="jack">      </div>
<div class="boxes"></div>
<div class="boxes"></div>
<div class="boxes"></div>
<div class="boxes"></div>
<div class="boxes"></div>
<div class="boxes"></div>
<div class="boxes"></div> </div>
</div>
```

and css:

```
#content_holder{
display: block;
position: relative;
margin: 0 auto;
margin-top:10px;
width: 910px;
min-height: 20px;}

.boxes{
display:block;
float: left;
width: 227.5px;
height:227.5px;}
#about{
background-image: linear-gradient(bottom, rgb(75,72,71) 0%, rgb(37,37,35) 69%);
background-image: -o-linear-gradient(bottom, rgb(75,72,71) 0%, rgb(37,37,35) 69%);
background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(bottom, rgb(75,72,71) 0%, rgb(37,37,35) 69%);
background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(bottom, rgb(75,72,71) 0%, rgb(37,37,35) 69%);
background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(bottom, rgb(75,72,71) 0%, rgb(37,37,35) 69%);

background-image: -webkit-gradient(
linear,
left bottom,
left top,
color-stop(0, rgb(75,72,71)),
color-stop(0.69, rgb(37,37,35))
);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm a little confused about what you are trying to accomplish from your code. Because your .boxes divs are floated, they will actually slip outside the #content_holder container unless you add the following css:

```
#content_holder:after{
    content: '';
    display: block;
    visibility: invisible;
    clear: both;
}
```

That will make sure your #content_holder wraps around your .boxes divs (which is what I assume you want, since they're inside it in the HTML). Your first box, the one with the img inside it, has no CSS styling at all in the code you provided, so it stretches to fill the whole line. Is that what you want, or do you want all the .boxes divs lined up in a row (or several rows)? If so, change the following line:

```
.boxes{
```

to this:

```
.boxes, .boxes_8{
```

This will cause the .boxes_8 div to let the other boxes in to the right of it.

What layout are you trying to achieve? If you elaborate, I could provide a more helpful answer.